# Set new value to complete row of 2-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I tried to set a new value on runtime to a complete row:

```
#definde ROW1  {1, 0}

int seq[5][2];

void test(void)
{
 seq[0] = ROW1;
}

Compiling error: 
expected expression before '{' token
#define ROW1   {1, 0}
```

Please help me!
Many thanks!

Comment: Arrays are not assignable as you're in C, and that includes the arrays in an array of arrays (which is what `seq` is. You need to set each element either by direct assignment (usually with loop(s)), or bulk memory copy if appropriate for your specific context.

Answer (score 0):

You cant assign arrays you need to copy them - for example:

```
#define ROW1  {1, 0}
#define ASSIGN(arr, init, type) memcpy(arr, (type[])init, sizeof((type[])init))

int seq[5][2];

void test(void)
{
     ASSIGN(seq[0], ROW1, int);
}
```

you can also initialize it :

```
int seq[5][2] = {[0] = ROW1};
```